# Calendar Web part Not showing calendar items

Tags: web-part, calendar, view

When I select a specific view for a calendar web part and "apply" the settings, the web part shows the view correctly (with the calendar items). However once I have "saved", the settings I have selected do not appear in the web part view. I've confirmed that the View I have selected includes the items that should be viewable, however nothing is populating in my web part view.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have publishing enabled? Do you require check-in and check-out on the page that contains the web part? If so, you may need to check-in the page and publish it.

Comment: Hi Justin, publishing is not enabled. I've also been able to manage/modify other web parts on the page successfully, but this one particular view of this calendar in the web part will not save....but it will appear when I "Apply" the settings, just not once I've saved

Comment: Hi Chelsea. Do you have the view in the public views or is it a personal view? Or, in web part -> layout, do you have "Hidden" checked? Also, in web part ->advanced, is the "Target Audience" blank? Sorry for all the questions.

Answer (score 0):

### Check your Web Part Page for additional hidden calendars.

Choose Edit Properties from the Page tab of the ribbon. From there, select "Open Web Part Page in maintenance view." Check and delete any extra calendars you don't want, or, to be safe, delete all of them and re-add the calendar you want.

Source: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2113462-o365-sharepoint-calendar-blank-on-team-site-but-events-show-in-calendar-view